# Replacing list tag with something if it lies in between a group of span tags

Tags: php, html, regex

Right now I have used preg_replace to replace li tag with my replacement if li and /li both lie in between 2 span opening and closing tags, but the problem is, Example my input:

```
<span style="background-color:green"> <li> one </li> </span> 
<li> second </li> <span style="background-color:green"> <li>  new  </li></span>
```

Output:

```
<span style="background-color:green"> <replacement> one </li> </span> 
<replacement> second </li> <span style="background-color:green"> replacement new 
</li> </span>
```

The 2nd replacement is the thing that I actually don't want. The logic that has been created is definitely that when it lies between span opening and closing tag, so according to the logic it is working fine, because it is seeing span opening and closing tag at the beginning and the end, and both li opening and closing are inside it as well. But I just want that if li opening and closing tags are a part of the span opening and closing tag, then it should be replaced otherwise not.
My required output:

```
<span style="background-color:green"> <replacement> one </li> 
</span> <li> second </li> <span style="background-color:green"> replacement new 
</li> </span>
```

My php code is:

```
preg_replace('/(<span style="background-color:green".+>.+)(<li>)(.+<\/li>.+<\/span>)/', '$1 replacement $3', $myinput);
```

Comment: the problem with your regex is that when you include the closing `</span>` for match in it, the code assumes the first opening `<span>` and last closing `</span>` which replaces every `<li>` as given in replacement.

Comment: Also, you are not telling the function to replace `</li>`. So you need two fixes, remove `</span>` form regex and replace `</li>` with `replacement`. See my answer below.

Comment: I just have to replace <li> with <li style="color:green">, I don't want to replace /li

Comment: My bad, didn't read the question carefully. see and edit to my answer.

Comment: By the way, I don't get your HTML!! why would you put `<li>` inside `<span>`. Former is block element while latter is an inline element... But that's a completely different topic which you need to look into..

Comment: It is a very complex task and I need to this wrong HTML thing purposely in order to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex was considering the every `<li>` before the last `<span>` in HTML, read my comment to the question. You can always test your regex at [PHP Live Regex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/) or any other similar service.

```
preg_replace("/(<span\sstyle=\"background-color:green\">)\s(<li>)(.+?)(<\/li>)/i", "$1<replacement>$3</replacement>", $myinput);
```

`\s` is to match any white-space and `i` option in the end is to make the match case-insensitive. You can additionally include `m` option to tell that it is a multi-line string. Read more in [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Everything is pretty straight forward. No explanation is required if you already know regex. Check [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php)

**EDIT:** minor modifications may be required in code to handle white space in output, which I'll assume can be corrected by you. Anyways, I wouldn't care about it as long as the regex works.

**EDIT2:** Reading the question carefully after comment from author, closing`<li>` need not be changed. Also, needs to account for any word/non-word characters between `<span>` and `<li>`. For this, something like below can be used:

```
preg_replace("/(<span\sstyle=\"background-color:green\">)(.+?)(<li>)(.+?)(<\/li>)/", "$1$2 replacement $4$5", $input_lines);
```

Comment: and what if there are optional characters or special characters in between span and li?? Should I use ?\w*?\W*?? I have replaced </replacement> with $4 ?\s*?\w*\W* would it be okay?? Because there is a possibility that there could be any special character, any character or any space in between

Comment: `preg_replace("/(<span\sstyle=\\"background-color:green\\">)(.+?)(<li>)(.+?)(<\/li>)/", "$1$2 replacement $4$5", $input_lines);`

Comment: @MariumMalik Just use `(.+?)` instead of `\s` to capture everything and then modify your replacement string accordingly.. See edit2.

Comment: But I have another concern, even if there is no li tag closing before span it still replaces li. After closing span, there could be closing li tags, so maybe it is considering those.

Comment: anything in between except </span> before </li> tag,I think this is what we need to do

Comment: Can you share a [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/). I'm unable to understand exactly what you need.

Comment: If li opening as well as closing tag lie between span opening and closing tag, then only li should be replaced. If li closing tag is not present in between span opening and closing, then should not be replaced.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/06d5e7d2de2614038845f524e21d920965d6e504   The last li does the wrong thing @Fr0zenFyr

Comment: Just replace `(<\/li>)` with `(<\/li>)\s(<\/span>)` in your regex. so `(<span\sstyle=\"background-color:green;\">)(.+?)(<li>)(.+?)(<\/li>\s<\/span>)`. [See in sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/500df5fcafa0940325589851d514bbc9e3ae6efa).

Comment: Gets messed up again. Working the same as my regex was working before. See here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f503cd916c91ea06f39ca3e477d681c9f6d633a3

Comment: Between li closing and span closing, there could be any characters or spaces but not the span opening tag. I have been trying the same from a week, have tried so many regex patterns, but failed to do so.

Comment: `preg_replace("/(<span style=\"background-color:green;\">)([\w\s]+)(<li>)([\w\W\s]+)[^sp]+(<\/li>)(.*)/im", "$1$2<replacement>$4$5$6", $input);` should work for your exact example pattern. Didn't test it. It is difficult to cover every possible situation if you don't mention the exact requirement in question. Moreover, it is a general understanding that using regex to manipulate HTML gives undesired results, so it is recommended by most people to avoid regex on HTML.